# How to set up Intellij so when I open a class it can run properly no matter the directory?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm a Java beginner and came from JGrasp where I could simply open up a class anywhere and be able to run it without any problems. When I open a class in Intellij it says the configuration isn't correct. Is there a way to set up Intellij by default to automatically set up the SDK for everything to default and allow me to open up any class without setting up configuration for each one. I attached an image that shows the edit configuration popup for a directory I opened. I am aware how to set up a project from scratch but I'd like to be able to open up code from anywhere without too much hassle setting up SDKs and configurations every time.

Here is the code :
 [image]

Comment: it is better you can provide code other than image of code.

Comment: Since you didn't include the code in your question (as text), it's difficult to say exactly what your challenge is, but the usual answer to this question is "use Maven or Gradle". In this case, it may be "stop using subfolders without accompanying packages".

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run a class, you first need that class to have a "psvm" (`public static void main`, which can be easily generated for you by simply writing "psvm" when you're coding a new method in a class).

Once that's done, you head over to the left, in your project's folder-tree, right-click your class, and press the "Run" button.

[image: Project's folder-tree]

The green arrow on top of the class' blue circle indicates that this class has a "psvm" and that you thus can "Run" it.

[image: psvm indicator]

After having done this once, IntelliJ will remember that you have ran this class and the "Edit confirguration" dropdown should usually always allow you to select it. Once the class you want to Run from that dropdown is selected, you can simply press the green triangle next to it.

[image: Quicker second access]

Answer (score 0):

You should place the source code (that is file with .java extension) to a separate directory (from the compiled classes (that is file with .class extension) and set it as a source root in IDEA: right click on the folder which server as a root package directory and select -> Mark As -> Source Root.